# Problems parsing StreamR JSON data

Tags: r, json, parsing, twitter, stream

I am attempting to use the `streamR` in R to download and analyze Twitter, under the pretense that this library can overcome the limitations from the `twitteR` package.

When downloading data everything seems to work fabulously, using the `filterStream` function (just to clarify, the function captures Twitter data, just running it will provide the json file -saved in the working directory- that needs to be used in further steps):

`filterStream( file.name="tweets_test.json",
              track="NFL", tweets=20, oauth=credential, timeout=10)`

```
Capturing tweets...
Connection to Twitter stream was closed after 10 seconds with up to 21 tweets downloaded.
```

However, when moving on to parse the `json` file, I keep getting all sorts of errors:

`readTweets("tweets_test.json", verbose = TRUE)`

```
0 tweets have been parsed.
list()
Warning message:
In readLines(tweets) : incomplete final line found on 'tweets_test.json'
```

Or with this function from the same package:

`tweet_df <- parseTweets(tweets='tweets_test.json')`

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "country_code", value = NA) :
```

replacement has 1 row, data has 0
   In addition: Warning message:
   In stream_in_int(path.expand(path)) : Parsing error on line 0

I have tried reading the `json` file with `jsonlite` and `rjson` with the same results.

Originally, it seemed that the error came from special characters `({, then \)` within the `json` file that I tried to clean up following the suggestion from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721575/struggling-to-import-nz-companies-extract-into-r-json), however, not much came out of it.

I found out about the `streamR` package from this [post](https://stats.seandolinar.com/collecting-twitter-data-getting-started/), which shows the process as very straight forward and simple (which it is, except for the parsing part!).

If any of you have experience with this library and/or these parsing issues, I'd really appreciate your input. I have been searching non stop but haven't been able to locate a solution.

Thanks!